# Change location of x-axis in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to plot a graph with a set of x-values and y-values in gnuplot. By default. the x-axis is drawn at y=0; I need to change the location of x-axis at y=1 and not at y=0. I was trying options with set xzeroaxis. How do I go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the x-axis is drawn at the bottom border of the graph. `xzeroaxis` controls only if the x-axis through the origin is drawn or not.

In any case, if you want to have a line at y=1, you can just draw the line there:

```
gnuplot> set arrow from  graph 0, first 1 to graph 1, first 1 nohead
gnuplot> plot x
```

Tick-marks won't be there, though.

However, if you mean that you want to shift the bottom of the graph to y=1, just use `set yrange [1:*]`.